# In which way Lebesgue Integral integrates over values?

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

[A special tutorial for full dummies](http://webbuild.knu.ac.kr/~trj/Analysis/Chandalia.pdf) says

> In order to distinguish between the Lebesgue and Reimann integrals
>   consider the values that the function f can take to be on the x-axis
>   (called the domain of the function) and the values of the function
>   evaluated at the chosen points to be on the y-axis (called the range
>   of the function). The Lebesgue integral defines the sub-intervals
>   along the range of the function and the Riemann integral defines them
>   along the domain of the function.

A thorough specification, introducing the Lebesgue integral in terms of sequences of countable sets and measures, precedes this conclusion. I am lost in all of these measure spaces. I do not see how integration over y axis follows from them. Can you draw the parallels, probably giving some examples? I feel like Lebesgue integral lacks examples.

Answer (score 2):

For a nonnegative function $f$, you can introduce a family of sets $\{ \{ A_{k,n} \}_{k=0}^{n^2} \}_{n=1}^\infty$, where $A_{k,n}=\{ x : k/n \leq f(x) < (k+1)/n \}$ for $k<n^2$ and $A_{n^2,n}=\{ x : f(x) \geq n \}$. This is a partition of the domain, which is given by dividing up the range into intervals and taking the preimage of each of these intervals under $f$. If $f$ is measurable, then the sets $A_{k,n}$ are all measurable. Thus you have a sequences of numbers $I_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n^2} \frac{k}{n} m(A_{k,n})$. Each $I_n$ is the integral of a "simple function", which is equal to $k/n$ on $A_{k,n}$.

It turns out that $\lim_{n \to \infty} I_n = \int f dm$. So while the Riemann integral approximates functions by functions which are constant on intervals, the Lebesgue integral approximates functions by functions which are constant on general measurable sets.

Similar to the Riemann case, actually computing an integral this way is usually hard. One case where it can be done is when $f$ is increasing: in this case the sum above is the left Riemann sum of $f$, albeit in general over a non-uniform partition. You might try writing out the calculation of $\int_0^1 x^2 dx$ by this method for instance.

Comment: I did get almost everything what you said except may be $n^2$. But, I wanted to see how your definition comes from the textbook definition. What is the measure here? Why do definitions speak about countable infinite sets and $\sigma$-algebras. What are all these in your example?

Comment: @ValentinTihomirov The $n^2$ comes because I want to subdivide the interval $[0,n]$ (which tends to $[0,\infty)$ into intervals of length $1/n$ (which tends to zero), so I need a total of $n^2$ subintervals. The choice of $[0,n]$ and $1/n$ is not important, I could have chosen to subdivide $[0,a_n]$ into intervals of length $b_n$, for any positive sequences $a_n$ tending to $\infty$ and $b_n$ tending to zero. Anyway, the measure here is $m$. It could be any measure, but the intuition arises from the case where it is the Lebesgue measure on the real line.

Comment: @ValentinTihomirov As for the general definitions, in the case of the Lebesgue measure on the real line, you do not need to formulate these definitions. The one conceptual leap that is required is the Caratheodory construction (take the outer measure and then restrict it to the measurable sets), which extends the domain of the measure from intervals to a much larger collection of sets. This idea is actually quite hard to motivate. But once you have the Lebesgue measure on the real line, the fact that it satisfies the axioms of a general measure space is then a *theorem*, not a definition.

Answer (score 0):

If you draw a picture of function f (for clarity, single varibale) with x as horizontal axis. You have two ways to slice area enclosed by f from x = a to x = b, and y = 0 with infinitimal rectangular bars, and sum them. Riemann integral said "let us slice them into vertical infinitesmal rectangular bars and sum the area of vertical infinitesmal rectangular bars. Lebesgue said how about we slice them with horizontal infinitesmal bars and sum over horizontal infinitesmal bars?

It turns out that if the summation in Riemann way converges, you can do it in Lebesgue way and get the same value, and not other way around.

In plain language, Lebesgue way solves a problem that a single value of f might have positive measure of the domain corresponding to it that Riemann way misses.

Comment: Really? Basically, you say that Lebesgue does integrate (slices) area over y whereas x integrates over x. Now, how does it answer my question?

Comment: Frankly I don't think there is any good "plain language" explanation of a non-Riemann integrable function.

Comment: @Ian I look at Lebesgue because it is referred to by Probability theory rather than the goal to integrate crank functions.

Comment: @ValentinTihomirov I was just criticizing the last paragraph of the answer above a little bit. The "problem" in Riemann integration solved by Lebesgue integration is really about completeness: pointwise limits of Riemann integrable functions need not be Riemann integrable, but pointwise limits of Lebesgue integrable functions are Lebesgue integrable. This means that the common problem of interchanging limit and integration can be handled in the Lebesgue framework and really can't be handled in the Riemann framework.

Comment: I intend to explain the difference  without using jagons. It could say to remove the limitation of subdivion of interval along x-axis posed by Riemann way, Lebesgue way makes use the new tool of the measure to measure the non-interval-based division along x-axis.

Comment: @runaround That is obvious as it is repeated all the time as well as the fact that Lebesgue intechanges the axis of integration. Yet, my question is how do you arrive at that with all the Borel sets used to introduce the measures and new kind of integration.

Comment: @ValentinTihomirov It's sort of the other way around, both historically and in terms of modern intuition. You come to the idea of partitioning the range and taking preimages in the setting of the real line, and then abstract measure theory is the natural generalization. Unfortunately some presentations prefer to basically start with abstract measure theory, which I find very hard to interpret.